# COLOR-PUZZLE.2. Complete the picture

Tags: cipher, visual

I have made another color puzzle. Try complete the picture.

[image]

Edit made!

Hint1:

> Time....

Hint2:

> There are **twelve** segments for a reason...

Hint3(last one):

> Numbers? Or what...?

Comment: For anybody who hasn't noticed, there are very tiny numbers at the top right of each rectangle

Comment: There was no need for them to be that small so i made them bigger.

Comment: Anyone trying? If so, i can give one last hint. But this hint will pretty much be a major one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's:

> [image: ![monthsofayear]
>
>  Use A1Z26 to get the letters:
>
>  Blue: F,A
>  Red: M,S,D
>  Grey: J
>  Yellow: O,N
>
>  and colour the months of the year in appropriately (January=1, go clockwise).

Comment: Yes, correct. Well done :)